# Perform a Test-Path for the current logged on user

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am trying to use $Env:userprofile to check for a folder for the current logged on user.  I have tried the following.

```
$Env:userprofile'OneDriveLocalCache'
Test-Path { ($env:USERProfileOneDriveLocalCache) }
[Environment]::GetFolderPath("C:\users\username\OneDriveLocalCache")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my machine, the environment variable `ONEDRIVE` exists, the value is the location of my onedrive folder, the following is very verbose, but does what you want:

```
$OneDrivePath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ONEDRIVE",[EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
Test-Path -Path $OneDrivePath
```

the following should likely work as well, without being as verbose, but it doesnt explicitly ensure the onedrive env var is a user var.

```
test-path -path $env:OneDrive
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the environment variable of OneDrive, what you will have to do is do is 
Build the path and test the path.

```
$Path = Join-Path -Path $env:UserProfile -ChildPath 'OneDriveLocalCahce'
Test-Path -Path $Path

#Here is a oneliner
Join-Path -Path $env:UserProfile -ChildPath 'OneDriveLocalCahce' | Test-Path
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I will give this a go today.

Comment: I used the oneliner and changed the 'OneDriveLocalCache' to the actual folder name and it worked like a champ.  Thank you again.

Comment: You can mark this as answer, it will help others with similar question.